# Problems using Gradle console command (gradlew)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm compiling a project with gradlew command in console and i'm getting this error:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.775 secs
Err:
Err:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Err:
Err:* What went wrong:
Err:A problem occurred configuring project ':capLibrary'.
Err:> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':capLibrary:_debugCompile'.
Err:   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1.
Err:     Searched in the following locations:
Err:         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.pom
Err:         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.jar
Err:     Required by:
Err:         CapAndroid:capLibrary:unspecified
Err:   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0.
Err:     Searched in the following locations:
Err:         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.5.0/play-services-7.5.0.pom
Err:         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/7.5.0/play-services-7.5.0.jar
Err:     Required by:
Err:         CapAndroid:capLibrary:unspecified
```

I don't know what is going wrong, these are my gradle dependencies:

For the application module:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':capLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

For the library module ( `capLibrary` ):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

This is the full gradle.build file for the library ( `capLibrary` ):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

This is the full gradle.build for the application module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.launcher"
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 10
        }

        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file("dummy")
                storePassword "dummy"
                keyAlias "dummy"
                keyPassword "dummy"
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            }
            debug {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':capLibrary')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Android SDK Manager.

> tip: in console write >> android [enter]

and install from  Android SDK Manager / Extras:

- Android support repository
- Google repository

Answer (score 0):

Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1.
Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0.

The library project can not find these support libraries.

Please check this. See if this helps.

Go to project structure and from modules select your capLibrary module. Check its dependencies. If not present, add v4 support and play services and build project.